# Non-math person needs verification re: their set notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Here is what I am attempting to say is:

"For every b in B, there is a set of r's such that for every v in V, there exists exactly one r"

$$\forall b \in B \{r \ | \ \forall v \in V, \exists ! r \}$$

In a similar vein, is it correct to say:

$$ X = \{y = \sum j(k) \ | \ \forall c \in C, \exists ! y\}$$

Here, I am trying to say:

"There is some set X that is made up of y's (which are calculated via the summation of j(k) ) such that for every c in C, there exists only one y."

I tried the Wikipedia page for set builder notation, but all that did was confuse me even more.

Another way to frame it is:

I have a set of things that I value (V). For example, lets say SEX, DRUGS, and ROCK-AND-ROLL (or v1, v2, v3 if you prefer). I also have, at any given moment, a set (B) of actions (b1, b2, b3) that I can undertake. Every possible action in the set of all possible actions will yield exactly one return (r) for everything that I value. That is, every b from the set B will generate exactly one r for every v in V.

Comment: Is the $r$ that is paired with each $v$ somehow determined by that $v$?  Should the phrase not continue "there exists exactly one $r$ *such that...*."  The way you have it phrased at the moment makes it sound like there is exactly one $r$ **total** and that it is the same $r$ for every $v$ and that there is no relationship between the $r$'s and the $v$'s at all.

Comment: when you quantify a variable, i.e., when you use "for all" and "exists", you must give some sort of statement about the variable, logically speaking, "exists x" or "exists only one x" makes no sense alone, you must complement it with "exists only one x such that something about x is valid". Try to adapt that on your thinking.

Comment: I have some set B that is comprised of a bunch of b's.
I have another set V that is comprised of a bunch of v's.

What I need is one set, made of r's, for every b in B. However, every v in V must map to an r in each of the sets made of r's.  At least I think it's called a mapping. Basically, each v need to be linked in some way to an r.

Comment: I suspect this may be an x-y problem: (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) . If you tell us where this question comes from in the best English you can (in more detail than your next to last paragraph and your comment) , and tell us why you need set-builder notation rather than English we may be able to help. Please do that by editing the question, not in a comment.

Comment: Okay, let's try this:</br></br>

I have a set of things that I value (V). For example, lets say SEX, DRUGS, and ROCK-AND-ROLL (or v1, v2, v3 if you prefer). I also have, at any given moment, a set (B) of actions (b1, b2, b3) that I can undertake. Every possible action in the set of all possible actions will yield exactly one return (r) for everything that I value. That is, every b from the set B will generate exactly one r for every v in V.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at this given the extra information in the comment (which should be edited into the question).

I'll assume the "return" $r$ is a member of a set $R$ (which might be a nonnegative real number, but doesn't have to be). Then I think what you are describing is a *function* that assigns a member of $R$ to each pair $(v,b)$ where $v \in V$ and $b \in B$.

I'd make the names of the sets more descriptive - say WISHES and ACTIONS for $V$ and $B$, VALUES for $R$ and a function
$$
\text{return}: \text{WISHES} \times \text{ACTIONS} \to \text{VALUES}
$$